# jquery MonthYearDropdown

Tags: jquery-ui

I want show month and year in one dropdown on jQuery datetimepicker above the month/year navbar. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To show month and year you can use default options like this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({changeMonth: true,changeYear: true});
```

but if you mean you want to show month and year in single dropdown (like jan-2011, feb-2011) then you will need to hack it and add a new dropdown and fill it will all allowed months-years. You will probably want to set `minDate` and `maxDate` values.

Comment: Yes I want to set it as November 2011. Can you explain me how to do this. i dont want to ser minDate and maxDate

Comment: I went through jquery ui source (jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.js) and found that it constructs month, year dropdowns at a function on line 9426. You will need to hide (like `display:none`) month and year dropdowns and create your own dropdown for month-year and handle select change event for new dropdown. on select change handler you will need to set the jquery month and year (hidden) dropdowns to correct values so that calendar redraws. I don't think I will be able to find the time to implement this any soon.